# How to get a 64-bit integer back from Presto in R?

Tags: r, jdbc, presto

[This article](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/06/r-in-a-64-bit-world/) describes the state of 64-bit integers in R.

[This doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf) says

> R has no built-in type with lossless support for the full range of
>   64-bit or larger integers. Here, the following rules apply:
>
> Values are returned as numeric
>
> Conversion to character always returns a lossless decimal
>   representation of the data

When I fetch results from a Presto table with 64-bit ints, the results are numeric and mangled.  However, when I convert them with `as.character`, the results are character and mangled.

Have you successfully retrieved 64-bit integers from Presto?

Did you use DBI with the [Presto JDBC driver](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html), or is there another way?

Comment: Can you use [`cast`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html)`(field as varchar)` in your query? (I don't know Presto, but it sounds reasonable to expect that a query returning a character should be preserved as such.)

Comment: Pretty sure the R Presto pkg project takes PRs if you want to code in support for https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html (just b/c  support is not in base does not make the current state "sad". vast majority of ppl don't need default 64-bit integer support.) just curious as to which languages have an "un-sad" state? java & python both require non-'base' libs to use 64-bit ints, too.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Fair enough, I will remove my editorializing. I am sad whenever software returns something unexpected, but life is complicated.

Comment: (I gotta say I thought python and java had native 64-bit ints. Ugh.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a workaround than a fix, you can "encourage" `character` by [casting](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html) it in the SQL query:

```
select cast(field as varchar) as field, ...
```